# Are socket.io v0.9 and v1 compatible?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

Are socket.io v0.9 and v1 compatible? Can a client running v1 connect to a server running v0.9, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io v0.9.x client library and v1.0.x server are not compatible. I haven't tested vice versa, but I'm sure it won't work either, probably for very good reasons. 
V1 server, and the client library supplied by it, solve a number of issues previous versions had. I would highly recommend reading through the [release notes](http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#more-66) for v1 as it indicates a number of improvements over previous versions. Furthermore, see the [migration](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/) guide for the changes you need to make when switching from v0.9 to v1.

Answer (score 0):

All I know is There are some method has been changed, such as :

Emit to a specific socket id:

```
0.9:io.sockets.socket(socketid).emit();
1.0:io.sockets.connected[socketid].emit();
```

you can see more in [socket.io docs](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/).

so I think in most cases , they are not compatible.

But if you mean only the connection, I think is OK~

Answer (score 0):

I have many problems with socket.io 1.0. Connecting is totaly different then 0.9, and new documentation for 1.0 is bad...